# Using Regular Expression in Mvc 4 Razor View's cshttml page for jquery email validation

Tags: regex

My Jquery Regular expression for email validation throwing syntax error.
Error : "Unexpected character \". Below is my code. please anyone give me right solution.

```
function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Side note: `return filter.test(sEmail);` does exactly the same job as your `if else` statement ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the @ sign with two @@ alike so :

```
var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var filter = /^([-\w\.]+)@...
```

note the `-` upfront instead of `\w-\.`

`-` in between means range as in `[a-z]` here with `\w' it does not make sense.

btw whats with `\[` and `\]` after `@`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:.*)@(?:.*).(?:.*)
```